# Has <key> been disabled?

Tags: support, formatting

I've noticed I'm not able to use key button formatting like <key>ESC</key>.

Has it been disabled? And if yes, why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm sure is not `<key>` but `<kbd>` tags:

<kbd>ESC</kbd>

So no, the only issue is that you're using the wrong syntax.